# Setting attributes to null using a config file set by the user

Tags: java, attributes, avro

I am working on a project where I was asked to make it so that the user can enter attributes that they want obscured from a `.yml` config file. The attribute already has a value in it and it will be set to `null` based on whether the user wants that attribute obscured.

For example if the variable `String country = "Canada";` exists and the user specifies `"country"` in the config file, country will be set to `null`.

The class has `get` and `set` methods. But I don't really understand how I can set the attributes to `null`.

For example, I'd have to set the value to null like `Object.setCountry=null;` but I won't know what set method to use `Object.xxxx=null;`

Comment: Improved formatting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used reflection to solve this issue.